# Sort and Group by Time

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
Line Date    Time   Order   Qty
   3 1140531 24737  S215037 1
   3 1140531 24737  S215037 1
   2 1140531 14955  S215058 1
   2 1140531 14955  S215058 1
   2 1140531 24055  S215059 1
   2 1140531 24055  S215060 1
   3 1140530 25319  S215099 1
   3 1140530 25319  S215099 1
```

I need to be able to display the Line, work order, sum of qty (I need to show the order that was completed first on desc based on date and time). My end result should look like this:

```
Line     Order   Sum of Qty
2       S215058   2
2       S215059   1
2       S215060   1
3       S215099   2
3       S215037   2
```

Attempt:

I have a query that updates the data into a table where it's ordered by Line, Date, Time
then I apply the following query:

```
SELECT     Line, Order, Sum(Qty)
From MyTable
Group by Line, Order
```

When I group the items, it groups my Orders based on alphabetical order and not the time. Please help!

Comment: Please make it human-readable

Comment: order is a reserved word. Please provide your actual query.

Comment: `Group by` only groups, `Order by` orders.  But as Strawberry says, your column names need work, cant use reserved words like that.

Comment: SELECT     Line, myOrder, Sum(Qty)
From MyTable
Group by Line, myOrder

Comment: My actual column name is myOrder. I apologize for the confusion. WhenI group though I'm getting the "myOrder" column being ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel some contradiction between your description and expected result as you mention the word `desc`.  Anyway the following query will give you the end result.

```
SELECT `Line`, `Order`, Sum(Qty) 
From MyTable 
Group by `Line`, `Order` 
order by `Line`, `Date`, `Time`, `Order`;
```

SQL Fiddle here:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/456bf/8